# 3d effect using JazzyViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Below is the image of the effect i want. This effect has been achieved using JazzyViewPager. 
I tried to do the same but i'm not able to get the same effect. any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hey, How you managed to display partial view of Previous and Next view in JazzyVIewPager. I am stuck at the same point. Can you help me ?